# the variable in json has changed but index.js outputs the old one

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
interval = setInterval(function() {
  online = require("./../../server/oxide/data/online.json");
  if (online.ONLINE == -1)
  {
    client.user.setStatus(`dnd`);
    client.user.setActivity("server offline");
  }
  else if (online.ONLINE == 0)
  {
    client.user.setStatus(`idle`);
    client.user.setActivity("no one");
  }
  else
  {
    client.user.setStatus(`online`);
    client.user.setActivity(`Players ${online.ONLINE}/500`);
  }
  console.log(`update ${online.ONLINE}`)
}, 10000);
```

every 10 seconds online.ONLINE updating

index.js changes the variable only if i restart js file, but I can't restart it. can smb help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Node.js, `require` is cached after the first time it is called so every next call to it will not read from the file again. (Source: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching)

In order to solve this, you can make use of other Node.js functions such as [`fs.readFileSync` method](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) to read the file raw every time you need to read from the JSON file, example below:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

interval = setInterval(function () {
  const raw = fs.readFileSync('./../../server/oxide/data/online.json', 'utf-8');
  online = JSON.parse(raw);

  if (online.ONLINE == -1) {
    client.user.setStatus(`dnd`);
    client.user.setActivity('server offline');
  } else if (online.ONLINE == 0) {
    client.user.setStatus(`idle`);
    client.user.setActivity('no one');
  } else {
    client.user.setStatus(`online`);
    client.user.setActivity(`Players ${online.ONLINE}/500`);
  }
  console.log(`update ${online.ONLINE}`);
}, 10000);
```

(The first argument of `fs.readFileSync` is the path to the file whereas the second argument is for the encoding. It is important to use `utf-8` in most cases to ensure it supports all the different text encoding / languages you might have in your JSON file)